# jQuery scroll to top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I've got three divs of 100% height that make up a page. At the bottom of the first page, a button scrolls down 100% of the $(window).height. This scrolls the second div completely into view.

```
$('.arrowdown').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window).height()}, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

I've got the same button at the bottom of the second div (I want it to scroll the third div completely in to view).

At the moment I've got:

```
$('.arrowdowncontent').click(function(){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#jobs').offset().top }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Aaaaaaah! Help appreciated. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ please? we could use your html markup

Comment: @benbuffone can you please add a Fiddle with html to figure out more precisely what you need?

Comment: works fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dUKeY/2/ You need to post the relevant HTML/CSS if you want more help..

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help! Sorry for not posting the HTML. Looks like @GabyakaG.Petrioli 's solution worked out just fine. :)